# How wide does a door have to be for a cat running through it to interfere with itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, interference, wavelength

A cat runs through a door. Assuming h = 1 J s, mass of the cat is 1 kg, and the velocity of the cat is 1 m/s. Assume the cat is a quantum particle. How wide does this door have to be for the cat to interfere with itself?

I think what I am struggling with most here is the assumption one needs to make.
My instinct is telling me to use de Broglie's wavelength:

$\lambda = \frac{h}{p} = \frac{h}{mv} = \frac{1\,J\,s}{1\,kg\;1\,m/s} = 1\,\mbox{m}$

But how does one know that this is the width of the door?

Comment: Was the question given with the assumption that h = 1?

Comment: Look up: wave diffraction and interference.

Comment: Yes, it is testing understanding and logic

Answer (score 1):

The Planck constant is $6.626 × 10^{−34} J s$. The $\lambda$ consequently. In any case the slit should be of the order of magnitude of the wavelength in order to have diffraction. Clearly not applicable to an ordinary macroscopic object.

Comment: The question seems to be a situation where the Planck constant is instead 1, so obviously it falls apart when you use a real Planck constant, but I don't think that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scaled up version of single slit diffraction.

When a quantum object passes through an opening that is comparable in size to the de Broglie wavelength $\lambda$ of said object, diffraction occurs.

From Huygens' principle we can think of the slit as many small slits each being a separate emitter of waves which then interfere with each other. A single slit diffraction pattern can be seen on a screen that is far enough away from the opening.

And so the cat interferes with itself when the door width is comparable to it's de Broglie wavelength.